# Отправитель на кириллице

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

Как можно корректно передать имя отправителя на кириллице, данный код:

```
def send(self) -> None:
    if not self.checkParams():
        return

try:
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = self.__subject
    msg['From'] = self.__sender + ' <' + self.__emailAddress + '>'
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(self.__recipients)
    msg['Reply-To'] = self.__emailAddress
    msg['Return-Path'] = self.__emailAddress

    part_html = MIMEText(self.__massage, 'html')

    for file in self.__filePathList:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            filepath = file
            basename = os.path.basename(filepath)
            filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath)
            part_file = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream; name="{}"'.format(basename))
            part_file.set_payload(open(filepath, "rb").read())
            part_file.add_header('Content-Description', basename)
            part_file.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{}"; size={}'.format(basename, filesize))
            encoders.encode_base64(part_file)
            msg.attach(part_file)

    msg.attach(part_html)

    mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.__server)
    mail.login(self.__emailAddress, self.__password)
    mail.sendmail(self.__emailAddress, self.__recipients, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

отлично отправляет письмо с кириллицей в теме или в теле сообщения, но стоит только указать кириллицу в отправителе, получается каша:

> (550, b'your mailer sends invalid headers')

```
self.__sender + ' <' + self.__emailAddress + '>
```

собственно если я `self.__sender`
принудительно переведу в кодировку utf-8, то нечего не измениться. Как только я не пробовал изворачиваться, с переменной `self.__sender`, в итоге:

```
mail.sendmail(self.__emailAddress, self.__recipients, msg.as_string())
```

переменная `msg.as_string()` выдаст белеберду. Может нужно как то прогнать через `MIMEText` кириллицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был на поверхности - необходимо скопировать `msg.as_string()` в строку и добавить в эту строку, в поле отправителя, то что желаете нужным на кириллице + почта отправителя, иначе будет 505 ошибка в запросе. Далее полученную строку, принудительно форматнуть в `utf-8` и ее же отформатированную отправить в

`mail.sendmail(self.__emailAddress, self.__recipients, newFormatString)`